# Skiasharp is slow drawing text to SVG

Tags: skiasharp

I am drawing a large SVG using skiasharp consisting of 1000+ gird lines and text (and various other elements) and adding the text is very slow.
If I get the path of the text and draw that instead it is quick, 0.2s in example, but drawing the text directly is over 10s.
Drawing the path of the text means it does not add a  element to the svg so the text is not selectable and the file size is considerably bigger so it is not a viable solution.

I have tried setting various options on the SKFont or SKPaint but nothing affected the time taken.
Doing similar with the current version of the unmanaged skia code draw text and drawing the path of the text are equally fast but skiasharp is based on an older version.

Is there any way to get a text element on an SVG with skiasharp with similar performance to drawing the path of the text?

```
using var font = new SKFont
{
    Size = 50
};

using var paint = new SKPaint(font)
{
    Color = SKColors.Blue,
    Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
    StrokeWidth = 2
};

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

var svg1 = "Lines.svg";

using (var fs = new FileStream(svg1, FileMode.Create))
using (var svgCanvas = SKSvgCanvas.Create(new SKRect(0, 0, 1000, 100000), fs))
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 100000; y += 100)
    {
        svgCanvas.DrawLine(0, y, 1000, y, paint);
    }
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{svg1} {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();

var svg2 = "LinesTextPath.svg";

using (var fs = new FileStream(svg2, FileMode.Create))
using (var svgCanvas = SKSvgCanvas.Create(new SKRect(0, 0, 1000, 100000), fs))
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 100000; y += 100)
    {
        svgCanvas.DrawLine(0, y, 1000, y, paint);
        using var path = paint.GetTextPath($"Text{y}", 10, y);
        svgCanvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    }
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{svg2} {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

stopwatch.Reset();
stopwatch.Start();

var svg3 = "LinesText.svg";

using (var fs = new FileStream(svg3, FileMode.Create))
using (var svgCanvas = SKSvgCanvas.Create(new SKRect(0, 0, 1000, 100000), fs))
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 100000; y += 100)
    {
        svgCanvas.DrawLine(0, y, 1000, y, paint);
        svgCanvas.DrawText($"Text{y}", 10, y, paint);
    }
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{svg3} {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

Comment: wouldn't it be faster drawing everything to a memory canvas, then flush it and save result to file stream?

Comment: Using a MemoryStream and then writing to a FileStream doesn't make any difference, all the time is taken in the SKCanvas.DrawText call